# Get object out of other object

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I want to change this object:

```
{
    item1: 6,
    item2: {
        item3: 1,
        item4: 1
    },
    item4: 1,
    item5: {
        item3: 1,
        item1: 3
    }
}
```

to that object:

```
{
    item1: 9,
    item3: 2,
    item4: 2
}
```

So get all key: values from every object and insert and sum all of them in one object

My actual code:

```
function calculate_recipe(item, quantity) {
    if (json.options[item].material) {
        return quantity;
    } else {
        let crafting_quantity = json.craftable[item].quantity
        let ingredients = json.craftable[item].ingredients
        let items_needed = {}
        for (let ingredient in ingredients) {
            let ingredient_quantity = ingredients[ingredient]
            items_needed[ingredient] = calculate_recipe(ingredient, Math.ceil(quantity / crafting_quantity) * ingredient_quantity);
        }
        return items_needed
    }
}
```

`return items_needed` returns the first object that I showed before.

Comment: Can you please show any efforts you've done to solve this so we can help you where you are stuck? As it stands, this is too broad.

Comment: I added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a map for a recursive call for the nested objects and return a flat object.

```js
function getFlatSum(object, map = new Map) {
    Object.entries(object).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
            getFlatSum(v, map);
        } else {
            map.set(k, (map.get(k) || 0) + v);
        }
    });
    return Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(map, ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v })));
}

var data = { item1: 6, item2: { item3: 1, item4: 1 }, item4: 1, item5: { item3: 1, item1: 3 } },
    result = getFlatSum(data);

console.log(result);
```